# Is there a video of a double-slit experiment using walking oil droplets (aka dotwaves)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, double-slit-experiment, quantum-interpretations, bohmian-mechanics

I've heard there have been experiments with walking droplets in a double-slit setup, and I've seen videos of many of the other quantum phenomenons walking droplets can emulate, but I can't find one of the double slit experiment.

Are there any published videos of double slit experiments using walking oil droplets?

This video shows a single walking droplet in a two-slit environment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsaUX48t0w8 . But it would be great to see something like a time lapse demonstrating statistical patterns beyond the slits. If anyone wants to chime in about slit width and distance between slits in comparison to the wavelengths, I'd love to hear that too.

Comment: Last time such a question was asked, few people knew what oil-drop experiments were being referenced, so for those interested, here is one article describing such an experiment: https://www.quantamagazine.org/20140624-fluid-tests-hint-at-concrete-quantum-reality/

Comment: It's unclear to me what purpose would be served by this.  We know that the whole oil-drop thing does not work as a model of QM (and we knew that in the 1960s): why are people still thinking about it?  Is there something I'm missing here?  (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: I agree, what does the oil drop experiment have to do with quantum mechanics? The fact that the word drop is used reminds you that mass and gravity are involved and has nothing to do with light.

Comment: @tfb The importance is in studying how we can emulate quantum phenomenon with classical physics. Traditionally, people believed that quantum phenomenon were in a realm that couldn't be explained by classical-style cause and effect but were relegated to a new, entirely statistical regime. If scientists are successful in being able to emulate all *(or even some) quantum phenomenon with classical physics, it may lead to knowledge we can use to advance physics beyond the quantum.

Comment: @BT: Well, we *know* that we can't model QM with a classical system, and we've known this since 1964, which is why I wonder why people still persist in this.  Either QM is wrong, or it can't be modeled by a classical system with reasonable characteristics (and since last year's experiments I think it's now really extremely convincing that QM is not wrong).

Comment: @tfb See that's the thing, I'm not sure we *do* know that we can't model QM with a classical system. Has that been mathematically proven? As far as I'm aware, many of our collective assumptions of what couldn't be modeled with a classical system have not turned out to be true.

Comment: @BT: yes, that's exactly what [Bell's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) says: no local hidden-variable theory can agree with the predictions of QM (and non-local HVTs are not compatible with special relativity).

Comment: @tfb As far as I understand, that's true, but quantum mechanics seems to also be non-local in the case of entanglement, and so it has the same issue as any hidden variable theory that isn't covered by Bell's theorem.

Comment: @BT: it's only 'non-local' if you think there *is* a hidden variable theory (which necessarily has to be non-local).

Comment: @tfb Even if its probabilistic, wave-function collapse is a pretty hand-wavy way to explain entanglement. Is that how you're saying entanglement happens?

Comment: @BT: I'm not saying anything about how entanglement happens.  All I am saying is that this oil-drop nonsense *can not reproduce the predictions of QM*, which predictions are now very well tested and which turn out to be correct.  End of story.